# 'setClaims(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>)' is deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot, jjwt

This is my example code:

```
    private String createToken(Map<String,Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                //the token will be expired in 10 hours
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000* 60 * 60 *10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
    }
```

setClaims setSubject setIssuedAt setExpiration signWith are all deprecated

I need to use JWT in API, and the IDE tells me that the .signXXX method are deprecated, maybe it's because my dependency version is latest, my version is 0.12.5

Comment: The javadoc for the methods should tell you what it recommends to use instead. Does it not? I found this via a quick google search, for example: https://javadoc.io/doc/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.12.2/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtBuilder.html#setClaims(java.util.Map)

Comment: with builder pattern you shouldn't use "set" word for methods, they deprecated all methods beginning with that word to enbrace this modern naming convention, from `setSubject` docs: *"deprecated since 0.12.0 in favor of the shorter and more modern builder-style named subject(String)."*

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `set` from every method.
and for the `signWith()` method, modify it the way I did
note: see the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBNcB.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)